# How to send Authorization type Bearer Token in api without library in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, postman, nsurlsession

I need to send Token in api call. I am getting response in postman but not in my program. Here is the code I am using to send token in api :

```
func getUserDetail(methodName:String,methodType:String ,finished: @escaping ((_ responseData: Data)->Void))
    {
        let url = URL(string: "\(globalURL)api/v1/\(methodName)")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue(AuthTokenString, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
           //parsing response
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

using this code I get token expired. Here is how postman calls it:

[image]

In postman I am getting response. I think there is something wrong in the way I am sending the token. any help.

Comment: I'd suggest to use CodyFire lib :) https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/CodyFire

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, Postman abstracts away the specific details of HTTP headers associated with the different authorization schemes.

This should do it:

```
request.addValue("Bearer " + AuthTokenString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

See [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1) for details on the expected format.

Comment: Yes exactly. Now I get the response. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: @Rj19 if this answer resolved your issue, please accept it (green tick it).